# TypeError in tensorflow ScipyOptimizerInterface when using in Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to run an external optimizer using Keras' `TFOptimizer` wrapper and giving it a `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` but I'm not succeeding.

My model is this (very small example):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(6,))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))
```

I'm tried compiling with:

```
model.compile(optimizer=TFOptimizer(ScipyOptimizerInterface()))
```

But of course, it doesn't work because the `ScipyOptimizerInterface` constructor needs the `loss` parameter during initialization.

So, I created two own classes:

```
class CGTFOptimizer(object):
    def compute_gradients(self, loss, params):
        optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, method='cg')
        result = optimizer.minimize(loss)
        return result

class CGTF(TFOptimizer):
    """ Wrapper for TFOptimizer """
    def __init__(self):
       super(CGTF, self).__init__(optimizer=CGTFOptimizer())
```

And compiling the model with `model.compile(optimizer=CGTF())` succeeds but upon training I receive the following error from the `ScipyOptimizerInterface` call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 455, in _apply_op_helper
    as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 991, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor
    ctx=ctx))
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 774, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("training/TFOptimizer/Reshape_25:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "directly_with_tensorflow.py", line 136, in <module>
    cgd_model.fit(X_reference, y_reference, epochs=50, batch_size=5)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 841, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1590, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in _make_train_function
    params=self._collected_trainable_weights, loss=self.total_loss)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/optimizers.py", line 674, in get_updates
    grads = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, params)
  File "directly_with_tensorflow.py", line 113, in compute_gradients
    optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, method='cg')
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._packed_var = self._pack(self._vars)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py", line 259, in _pack
    return array_ops.concat(flattened, 0)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1099, in concat
    return gen_array_ops._concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 706, in _concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "venv/py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 483, in _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, int64] that don't all match.
```

This might be a problem within TensorFlow and not Keras? I tried different methods from casting the `loss` to `float32`, `float64`, or `int64` but nothing helped.

`X_reference` and `y_reference` have the shape `(10,6)`, `(10,5)` resp. with type `float32`.

Can someone point to me how I can use ScipyOptimizers within Keras?